# Do we need to lock to call a method c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Say I have the following code

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private int int_var = 0;
    private Object lock_obj = new Object();

    public void Setter(int new_val)
    {
        lock(lock_obj)
        {
            int_var = new_val;
        }
    }

    public int Getter()
    {
         lock(lock_obj)
         {
            return int_var; 
         }
    }
}
```

Now My question is can I call Setter in one thread and getter in another thread

someClass.Setter(32);

int x = someClass.Getter();

I am unsure if the variable someCLass will be corrupted when I call getter or setter in different thread.

thanks

Comment: The question is way too general to provide an answer. Sometime you would need to add lock, sometimes not... sometime adding lock will lead to deadlock and sometime not adding one will lead to broken code... It all depends on what you actually want to protect/ensure to be atomic.

Comment: The question is not possible to decide, because we do not know the scope of the lock and the actions. You can have one lock for the whole application or one lock for every instance of SomeClass. And you can access only things in the instance or completely anything anywhere. Not enough information.

Comment: It is impossible to say without knowing what `SomeClass`'s code looks like. e.g. how is `lock_obj` declared and instantiated. What does `// here I access some variable` do. etc etc.

Comment: Adding `lock` is not a replacement for understanding thread safety.

Comment: I edited my question so it better explain my goal. Is it clear enough ?